# Mysql summary from colums

Tags: php, mysql

I need to summary columns together on each row, like a leaderboard. How it looks:

```
Name | country | track 1 | track 2 | track 3 | Total 
John     ENG       32        56        24
Peter    POL       45        43        35
```

Two issues here, I could use the

`update 'table' set Total = track 1 + track 2 + track 3`

BUT it's not always 3 tracks, anywhere from 3 to 20.
Secound if I don't SUM it in mysql I can not sort it when I present data in HTML/php.

Or is there some other smart way to build leaderboards?

Comment: You may want to redesign your database, having a variable number of columns for the number of tracks isn't as maintainable as you may think.

Comment: Have a `track` as 1 column and store it as an integer. Then have `playlength` as another column (assuming that is what `track1` etc are storing).

Comment: Take a look at [database-normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redesign your table to have colums for name, country, track number and data Then instead if having a wide table with just 3 track numbers you have a tall, thin table with each row being the data for a given name, country and track.

Then you can summarise using something like

```
 SELECT 
     country, 
     name, 
     sum(data) as total
 FROM trackdata 
 GROUP BY
     name, 
     country
ORDER BY
    sum(data) desc
```

Take a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f11376/4) where I have made a SQL fiddle showing this working the way you want it

Depending upon your expected data however you might really be better having a separate table for Country, where each country name only appears once (and also for name maybe). For example, if John is always associated with ENG then you have a repeating group and its better to remove that association from the table above which is really about scores on a track not who is in what country and put that into its own table which is then joined to the track data.

A full solution might have the following tables

```
**Athlete**
athlete_id
athlete_name
(other data about athletes)

**Country**
country_id
country_name
(other data about countries)

**Track**
Track_id       
Track_number
(other data about tracks)

**country_athlete**   (this joining table allows for the one to many of one country having many athletes
country_athlete_id
country_id
athlete_id

**Times**
country_athlete_id   <--- this identifies a given combination of athlete and country 
track_id             <--- this identifies the track       
data                 <--- this is where you store the actual time
```

It can get more complex depending on your data, eg can the same track number appear in different countries? if so then you need another joining table to join one track number to many countries.

Alternatively, even with the poor design of my SQL fiddle example, it might be good to make name,country and track a primary key so that you can only ever have one 'data' value for a given combination of name, country and track. However, this decision, and that of normalising your table into multiple joined tables would be based upon the data you expect to get.

But either way as soon as you say 'I don't know how many tracks there will be' then you should start thinking 'each track's data appears in one ROW and not one COLUMN'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel like the fiddle example is the way to go. Insted of making a column for each track I can just make a Track column and then easely do a summary and sorting that way for php.
The complete solution is really good to but will not work in my case. I that case you have to have a fixed amount of tracks etc. In my case there are several competitions with different tracks in each competition.
So I want to have a new table for each competition with new cometitors and new tracks in each. That way the fiddle one is great

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned, you need to redesign your database. You need an **One-To-Many** relationship between your **Leaderboard** table and a new **Tracks** table. This means that *one* User can have  *many* Tracks, with each track being represented by a record in the Tracks table.

These two databases should be connected by a foreign key, in this case it could be a *user_id* field.

The `total` field in the leaderboard table could be updated every time a new track is inserted or updated, or you could have a query similar to the one you wanted. Here is how such a query *could* look like:

```sql
UPDATE leaderboard SET total = (
  SELECT SUM(track) FROM tracks WHERE user_id = leaderboard.user_id
)
```

I recommend you read about database relationships, here is a link:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 0):

I still get a lot of issues with this... I don't think that the issue is the database though, I think it's more they way I pressent the date on the web.
I'm able to get all the data etc. The only thing is my  is not filling up the right way.

```
What I do now is like: "SELECT * FROM `times` NATURAL JOIN `players`

Then <?php foreach... ?>
<tr>
<td>  <?php echo $row[playerID];?> </td>
<td>  <?php echo $row[Time];?> </td>
....
```

The thing is it's hard to get sorting, order and SUM all in ones with this static table solution.
I searched around for leaderboards and I really don't understand how they build theres with active order etc. like. https://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html
How do they build leaderboards like that? With sorting and everything.

Comment: First check that your natural join is using the right columns. Just because they have the same names does not mean they have the same meaning or values in common. I always use explicit  joins where I specify the columns that I want to take part in the join. However, if you are sure you have the right data then your question has changed from one about SQL to one about presenting the results of a query in tabular form using PHP. As such you would be better asking a new question. I have a ready made answer I can give you to a new question but you can't accept two answers for the same question.